# How to view logs in IBM bluemix NodeRED Application

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I have NodeRED application that running on IBM Bluemix. I have added WARN logs in NodeRED nodes. But those were unable to view in log console tab(In NodeRED debug tab able to see WARN logs are printing).

In the Advance view, with Kibana log analysis tool, we can able to see the sys logs. And all the incomming request logs are there. But NodeRED node WARN logs are not there. please let me know, how to view those logs ?

**EDIT**
Update the question with new finding. I have tested other NodeRED application, that created some months ago. It is printing WARN and ERROR. But this issue with the newly created NodeRED application(Created by one month ago). Logs are not added with this.

**EDIT 14/03/17**
After the application restart it automatically resolve the issue. Now logs are printing. Do not know the reason for actual issue. But solution is simple like restart.

Answer (score 1):

In debug node, are you sending it to both Debug tab & console?

You will have to select option "debug tab & console" ( as shown in image below) to view it in both.

[image]

Then, you will get it in both debug tab & console ( shown in image below)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried with this option also. But not success. Then what I do is, adding WARN logs inside function node. I tried with other bluemix nodered application that created some months ago. It is adding WARN logs from with that application. But new NodeRED application only has this issue. Sorry I did not do that testing, when I am posting question.

Comment: I just deployed new NODE RED app and tried it again. It's working.. Warning is displayed in both Console and debug tab.

Comment: It works for me also in NodeRed 16.2, running on Bluemix.  It is node.warn you are using, or something else?

Comment: it is node.warn("warn") and node.error("error"). Issue is it is working for some nodered applications, but not working for 2 months ago created application.

Comment: Is there a different in nodered versions between works|does not work?

Comment: This issue resolve after the restart, but thank you for the prompt support for the @RiyaMRoy and amadain.

Comment: @amadain yes, What you mentioned is valid. I copied the nodered flow from another application. May be due to that logs were not printing and after restart it resolves may be. Do not know actual reason.

Comment: Huh, interesting and probably good to know.  I would suggest you add that as an answer here, might help others.